# Single-particle partition function for rotational movement - angle degree of freedom

Tags: thermodynamics, angular-momentum

There are $N$ molecules on a $2-D$ plane. Each molecule has not only translational degrees of freedom, but is also able to rotate around the $z$ axis. The angular momentum is quantized and given by $L_z=\hbar m_z$, and the corresponding rotational energy is $\epsilon_{m_z}=\frac{L_z^2}{2I}=\frac{\hbar^2 m_z^2}{2I}$.

I need to calculate the single-particle partition function of the canonical ensemble, corresponding to the rotational movement. $z=\sum_{\mu _i} exp(-\beta H(\mu _i))$.

The solution says $z=\sum_{m_z=-\infty}^{\infty} exp(-\beta \frac{\hbar^2 m_z^2}{2I})$.

My question is, why isn't it $z=2\pi\sum_{m_z=-\infty}^{\infty} exp(-\beta \frac{\hbar^2 m_z^2}{2I})$. Where did the angle degree of freedom go? Or are we allowed to ignore it, and if yes, when? Don't $(L,\theta)$ always come as a pair in phase-space, like $(p,q)$?

Comment: Do you mean 'where did the *translational* degrees of freedom go'? Because the angle degree of freedom is $m_z$, since it's quantised...

Comment: @lemon - the angular momentum $L_z$ is quantized. Don't we need to have another degree of freedom in phase-space, $\theta$, the angle of rotation around the z axis, which will result in multiplying the partition function by $2\pi$?

Comment: In quantum mechanics conjugate pairs, such as $(q,p)$ or $(L,\theta)$, are linked by the uncertainty principle and so cannot be simultaneously specified. Consequently the pair, together only constitute 1 degree of freedom.

Comment: @BySymmetry Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.